What specifically does ':' mean along with a method in JavaScript?
I'm watching a class in which the following method is being created
getUsers(): Observable<User[]>{ // it will be an array of users
   return this.segurancaHttp.get<User[]>(this.BASE_URL + 'users') 
} 

What do the ":" after the method name mean? is the method receiving the observable? Can you say it like that?

That's Typescript, not JavaScript.

method(): type { ... } - What follows the : is the return type of the method, like myMethod(): void { /* ... */ }, or myOther(): string { return 'hello'; }, etc.

Thank you, I already corrected it, could you clarify my doubt? @Pointy

And what do these mean : ? @Tim Lewis

Sorry, what does... what mean? : is a colon...?

It's a return type annotation. The type after the colon is the return type of the function/method.

What you posted here is not plain JavaScript, but TypeScript, a typed version of JavaScript.
The : after a function or variable declaration denotes the type of the variable or - in your case - the return type of the function.
Thus, your function will return an Observable of an array of User objects.
Please be aware, that common browsers won't understand TypeScript natively, instead you need a compiler (usually tsc) to create a browser-friendly (=plain or "vanilla" JavaScript) version of your code.
